# firebase emulator initialization failure on database.rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-tools

When I upgraded to Firebase 8.12.1, the local database emulator gets a Java/JavaScript error parsing the database rules. I trimmed the original rules down to the smallest thing that breaks. Here's what database-debug.log shows, including the JSON input. Bug or did Firebase change some syntax? JSONLint says the JSON itself is OK.

```
ERROR com.firebase.core.namespace.NamespaceActor - Unexpected error caught in NamespaceActor(...) for AdminEnvelope(SecurityClaims(Some(GCloudToken(owner,GCloudOwner,1602893571,None)),None),UpdateRules({
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "tickets": {
      "$offering_id": {
        "tickets": {
            "blocks": {
              "$block_id": {
                ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['timestamp', 'text']"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
,false))
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.getCurrentContext(Context.java:346)
```

Comment: The CLI should not crash without a meaningful message.  If you think think there is a bug, file an issue on GitHub with your full steps to reproduce.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Thanks, Doug.  Did that and found what my own problem is, though there's still the Firebase bug.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2734

Comment: *My* problem BTW was a missing ) in the .validate string. So if others hit this, re-read your rules or run them through 
a JavaScript syntax checker. Firebase's correctly parses the JSON and sees the error but hits a snag logging it.